# jQuery, how to call a function while passing a variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, parameter-passing

I want to use jQuery's .get method to send an ajax call to the server.

I am using this line:

```
$.get("InfoRetrieve", { },addContent(data));
```

As you can see I want to call a function call addContent and pass it the data that is retrieved from the server.

The function addContent is below:

```
function addContent(data){
    $("#0001").append(data);
}
```

It doesn't seem to work, can you see why.

Comment: I am not passing any data at the moment, I have left the {} as I will be soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change it to:

```
$.get("InfoRetrieve", { },addContent);
```

It will take care of passing `data` when it calls the function.

Comment: When you tried to use it like this `addContent(data)`, you  were actually triggering the function, not passing a reference to it. By omitting the `(data)` you passed a reference to your function that `$.get` could call upon success.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in a new function object:

```
$.get("InfoRetrieve", { },function() { addContent(data) });
```